# Complex nested Elastic NEST Query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

How would I convert this to the equivalent Nest query?

```
{
"query": {
    "nested": {
        "path": "boundedContexts",
        "query": {
            "nested": {
            "path": "boundedContexts.aggregateRoots",
                "query": {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "boundedContexts.aggregateRoots.modelMetaData",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                    "must": [
                                        { "match": { "boundedContexts.aggregateRoots.modelMetaData.modelReferenceId": "4e7c5c0e-93a7-4bf6-9705-cf1327760e21" } },
                                        { "match": { "boundedContexts.aggregateRoots.modelMetaData.modelType.name": "AggregateRoot" } } 
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 1,
    "sort": [   
    {
    "generatedDate": {
        "order": "desc"
    }
    }
]
```

}

I am trying to generate an equivalent Nest query similar to this ..

```
  ISearchResponse<ViewModels.DomainModel> response = null;
            response = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<ViewModels.DomainModel>(s => s.Index(_modelMetadataProvider.CurrentIndexName)
            .Query(q => q.Nested(n1 => n1.Path("boundedContexts")
                .Query(q2 => q2.Nested(n2 => n2.Path("boundedContexts.aggregateRoots")
                    .Query(q3 => q3.Nested(n3 => n3.Path("boundedContexts.aggregateRoots.modelMetaData").
                       Query(q4 =>q4.Bool(b => b.Must(bs => 
                           bs.Match(p => p.Field("boundedContexts.aggregateRoots.modelMetaData.modelReferenceId")))))))))))
            .Size(1).Sort(s=>s.Descending("generatedDate")));
```

I am stuck on how to compare to a variable against at the p.Field("boundedContexts.aggregateRoots.modelMetaData.modelReferenceId")  level of query.

Comment: You can compare the field to a variable using the `Query` property on the `MatchQueryDescriptor` object. It looks like this `p.Field("boundedContexts.aggregateRoots.modelMetaData.modelReferenceId").Query("<myMatch>")`
For more information on the `MatchQueryDescriptor`, please take a look here - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/match-usage.html

Comment: I credited you @SaiGummaluri on this follow-on question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65738179/complex-nested-query-where-to-place-bool-match