# Complex Nested Query Where to Place Bool Match

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a complex index within Elastic that I need to query by 3 parameters.

Thanks to this [answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65727915/complex-nested-elastic-nest-query) I am able to query by 2 of the 3 parameters, however the 3rd parameter is not at the same nested level as the other two.

The schema looks this..
[image]

The following query works for the 2 of the 3 parameters...

[image]

But the 3rd parameter is at a different level the the other two so this query does not return the expected document.
[image]

Given that the bool match query for "boundedContexts.aggregateRoot.aggregateType.name" is at a different nested level, how would I write this query so that it will query on that field ?

Comment: Maybe you can break it down into two sub queries that can be compounded using a `bool` with a `must`. The first sub query is going to be on the path `boundedContexts.aggregateRoots.aggregateType` and the second one on the path `boundedContexts.aggregateRoots.modelMetaData`
You can repeat this pattern to suit your need

Comment: Thanks again @SaiGummaluri, I implemented a working solution based upon your comment.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This works...

```
{
"query": {
    "nested": {
        "path": "boundedContexts",
        "query": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "boundedContexts.aggregateRoots",
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                    { "match": { "boundedContexts.aggregateRoots.aggregateType.name": "Aggregate" } },
                                    { "nested": {
                                    "path": "boundedContexts.aggregateRoots.modelMetaData",
                                    "query": {
                                        "bool": {
                                                "must": [
                                                    
                                                    { "match": { "boundedContexts.aggregateRoots.modelMetaData.modelReferenceId": "4e7c5c0e-93a7-4bf6-9705-cf1327760e21" } },
                                                    { "match": { "boundedContexts.aggregateRoots.modelMetaData.modelType.name": "AggregateRoot" } } 
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 1,
    "sort": [   
    {
        "generatedDate": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }
```

]
}